# Ada: Array length modification when adding anew element

Tags: arrays, dynamic, ada, allocation

I try to create a dynamic array package. I have a generic package with a generic type and then I have declared in .ads an array (Positive indexes) of elements Elem_Type. I was curious if it is possible to create a procedure Append(Vector, Item) where to modify Vector's length, allowing him to take one more element. Something like when you have a buffer[100] in C and allocate him 1 more element to make it 101 then add something on position 101.

Comment: I don’t know any Ada, but note that in C, the realloc() function will often just allocate a new, larger array, copy the contents of the old one,  and return the new one. You can presumably implement that in Ada.

Comment: If you’re doing this out of academic interest, fine; see [Jere’s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56329081/40851). If not, look up [Ada.Containers.Vectors](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/rm12_w_tc1/html/RM-A-18-2.html).

Comment: ... or, if compiler portability is of no importance, have a look at [```GNAT.Table```](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gnat_rm/GNAT-Table-g-table-ads.html#GNAT-Table-g-table-ads) or [```GNAT.Dynamic_Tables```](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gnat_rm/GNAT-Dynamic_005fTables-g-dyntab-ads.html#GNAT-Dynamic_005fTables-g-dyntab-ads) (in GPS, see "Help > GNAT Runtime > GNAT > (Dynamic) Table"). These data structures are also used by GNAT internally (see, for example, [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/viewcvs/gcc/trunk/gcc/ada/atree.ads?view=markup#l4263)).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Ada the general way to do this is to create a new and bigger block, then copy the contents to it and free the old block.  I often suggest allocating new blocks in multiples of some large chunk size so you don't have to reallocate much.  So like if you have to allocate a new array, instead of adding just one extra element, add 500 (or some number that makes sense).

Note that even in C, the realloc() function often does exactly this.  It isn't common in non trivial projects for the realloc() function to be able to actually just add another element.  It often times has to create an entire new array and do the copy, just like I am suggesting for Ada.

Some other options in Ada include making your own storage pool that makes reallocating a lot easier and faster, but you have to come up with the algorithm on how to do that or find someone elses.  You can also do bindings to the C functions, but you cannot mix malloc/realloc/free with Ada's new/unchecked_deallocation

Answer (score 5):

it sounds like you want to use the generic package Ada.Containers.Vectors, or possibly the package Ada.Containers.Indefinite_Vectors. Those packages already define all the capabilities you seem to require.
The description of the generic package Ada.Containers.Vectors, as shown in the [Ada 2012 Reference Manual](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/12rm/html/RM-TTL.html) is

```
with Ada.Iterator_Interfaces;
generic
   type Index_Type is range <>;
   type Element_Type is private;
   with function "=" (Left, Right : Element_Type) return Boolean is <>;
package Ada.Containers.Vectors is
   pragma Preelaborate(Vectors);
   pragma Remote_Types(Vectors);

   subtype Extended_Index is
      Index_Type'Base range
         Index_Type'First-1 ..
         Index_Type'Min (Index_Type'Base'Last - 1, Index_Type'Last) + 1;
   No_Index : constant Extended_Index := Extended_Index'First;

   type Vector is tagged private
      with Constant_Indexing => Constant_Reference,
           Variable_Indexing => Reference,
           Default_Iterator  => Iterate,
           Iterator_Element  => Element_Type;
   pragma Preelaborable_Initialization(Vector);

   type Cursor is private;
   pragma Preelaborable_Initialization(Cursor);

   Empty_Vector : constant Vector;

   No_Element : constant Cursor;

   function Has_Element (Position : Cursor) return Boolean;

   package Vector_Iterator_Interfaces is new
       Ada.Iterator_Interfaces (Cursor, Has_Element);

   function "=" (Left, Right : Vector) return Boolean;

   function To_Vector (Length : Count_Type) return Vector;

   function To_Vector
     (New_Item : Element_Type;
      Length   : Count_Type) return Vector;

   function "&" (Left, Right : Vector) return Vector;

   function "&" (Left  : Vector;
                 Right : Element_Type) return Vector;

   function "&" (Left  : Element_Type;
                 Right : Vector) return Vector;

   function "&" (Left, Right  : Element_Type) return Vector;

   function Capacity (Container : Vector) return Count_Type;

   procedure Reserve_Capacity (Container : in out Vector;
                               Capacity  : in     Count_Type);

   function Length (Container : Vector) return Count_Type;

   procedure Set_Length (Container : in out Vector;
                         Length    : in     Count_Type);

   function Is_Empty (Container : Vector) return Boolean;

   procedure Clear (Container : in out Vector);

   function To_Cursor (Container : Vector;
                       Index     : Extended_Index) return Cursor;

   function To_Index (Position  : Cursor) return Extended_Index;

   function Element (Container : Vector;
                     Index     : Index_Type)
      return Element_Type;

   function Element (Position : Cursor) return Element_Type;

   procedure Replace_Element (Container : in out Vector;
                              Index     : in     Index_Type;
                              New_Item  : in     Element_Type);

   procedure Replace_Element (Container : in out Vector;
                              Position  : in     Cursor;
                              New_item  : in     Element_Type);

   procedure Query_Element
     (Container : in Vector;
      Index     : in Index_Type;
      Process   : not null access procedure (Element : in Element_Type));

   procedure Query_Element
     (Position : in Cursor;
      Process  : not null access procedure (Element : in Element_Type));

   procedure Update_Element
     (Container : in out Vector;
      Index     : in     Index_Type;
      Process   : not null access procedure
                      (Element : in out Element_Type));

   procedure Update_Element
     (Container : in out Vector;
      Position  : in     Cursor;
      Process   : not null access procedure
                      (Element : in out Element_Type));

   type Constant_Reference_Type
         (Element : not null access constant Element_Type) is private
      with Implicit_Dereference => Element;

   type Reference_Type (Element : not null access Element_Type) is private
      with Implicit_Dereference => Element;

   function Constant_Reference (Container : aliased in Vector;
                                Index     : in Index_Type)
      return Constant_Reference_Type;

   function Reference (Container : aliased in out Vector;
                       Index     : in Index_Type)
      return Reference_Type;

   function Constant_Reference (Container : aliased in Vector;
                                Position  : in Cursor)
      return Constant_Reference_Type;

   function Reference (Container : aliased in out Vector;
                       Position  : in Cursor)
      return Reference_Type;

   procedure Assign (Target : in out Vector; Source : in Vector);

   function Copy (Source : Vector; Capacity : Count_Type := 0)
      return Vector;

   procedure Move (Target : in out Vector;
                   Source : in out Vector);

   procedure Insert (Container : in out Vector;
                     Before    : in     Extended_Index;
                     New_Item  : in     Vector);

   procedure Insert (Container : in out Vector;
                     Before    : in     Cursor;
                     New_Item  : in     Vector);

   procedure Insert (Container : in out Vector;
                     Before    : in     Cursor;
                     New_Item  : in     Vector;
                     Position  :    out Cursor);

   procedure Insert (Container : in out Vector;
                     Before    : in     Extended_Index;
                     New_Item  : in     Element_Type;
                     Count     : in     Count_Type := 1);

   procedure Insert (Container : in out Vector;
                     Before    : in     Cursor;
                     New_Item  : in     Element_Type;
                     Count     : in     Count_Type := 1);

   procedure Insert (Container : in out Vector;
                     Before    : in     Cursor;
                     New_Item  : in     Element_Type;
                     Position  :    out Cursor;
                     Count     : in     Count_Type := 1);

   procedure Insert (Container : in out Vector;
                     Before    : in     Extended_Index;
                     Count     : in     Count_Type := 1);

   procedure Insert (Container : in out Vector;
                     Before    : in     Cursor;
                     Position  :    out Cursor;
                     Count     : in     Count_Type := 1);

   procedure Prepend (Container : in out Vector;
                      New_Item  : in     Vector);

   procedure Prepend (Container : in out Vector;
                      New_Item  : in     Element_Type;
                      Count     : in     Count_Type := 1);

   procedure Append (Container : in out Vector;
                     New_Item  : in     Vector);

   procedure Append (Container : in out Vector;
                     New_Item  : in     Element_Type;
                     Count     : in     Count_Type := 1);

   procedure Insert_Space (Container : in out Vector;
                           Before    : in     Extended_Index;
                           Count     : in     Count_Type := 1);

   procedure Insert_Space (Container : in out Vector;
                           Before    : in     Cursor;
                           Position  :    out Cursor;
                           Count     : in     Count_Type := 1);

   procedure Delete (Container : in out Vector;
                     Index     : in     Extended_Index;
                     Count     : in     Count_Type := 1);

   procedure Delete (Container : in out Vector;
                     Position  : in out Cursor;
                     Count     : in     Count_Type := 1);

   procedure Delete_First (Container : in out Vector;
                           Count     : in     Count_Type := 1);

   procedure Delete_Last (Container : in out Vector;
                          Count     : in     Count_Type := 1);

   procedure Reverse_Elements (Container : in out Vector);

   procedure Swap (Container : in out Vector;
                   I, J      : in     Index_Type);

   procedure Swap (Container : in out Vector;
                   I, J      : in     Cursor);

   function First_Index (Container : Vector) return Index_Type;

   function First (Container : Vector) return Cursor;

   function First_Element (Container : Vector)
      return Element_Type;

   function Last_Index (Container : Vector) return Extended_Index;

   function Last (Container : Vector) return Cursor;

   function Last_Element (Container : Vector)
      return Element_Type;

   function Next (Position : Cursor) return Cursor;

   procedure Next (Position : in out Cursor);

   function Previous (Position : Cursor) return Cursor;

   procedure Previous (Position : in out Cursor);

   function Find_Index (Container : Vector;
                        Item      : Element_Type;
                        Index     : Index_Type := Index_Type'First)
      return Extended_Index;

   function Find (Container : Vector;
                  Item      : Element_Type;
                  Position  : Cursor := No_Element)
      return Cursor;

   function Reverse_Find_Index (Container : Vector;
                                Item      : Element_Type;
                                Index     : Index_Type := Index_Type'Last)
      return Extended_Index;

   function Reverse_Find (Container : Vector;
                          Item      : Element_Type;
                          Position  : Cursor := No_Element)
      return Cursor;

   function Contains (Container : Vector;
                      Item      : Element_Type) return Boolean;


   procedure  Iterate
     (Container : in Vector;
      Process   : not null access procedure (Position : in Cursor));

   procedure Reverse_Iterate
     (Container : in Vector;
      Process   : not null access procedure (Position : in Cursor));

   function Iterate (Container : in Vector)
      return Vector_Iterator_Interfaces.Reversible_Iterator'Class;

   function Iterate (Container : in Vector; Start : in Cursor)
      return Vector_Iterator_Interfaces.Reversible_Iterator'Class;

   generic
      with function "<" (Left, Right : Element_Type)
         return Boolean is <>;
   package Generic_Sorting is

      function Is_Sorted (Container : Vector) return Boolean;

      procedure Sort (Container : in out Vector);

      procedure Merge (Target  : in out Vector;
                       Source  : in out Vector);

   end Generic_Sorting;

private

   ... -- not specified by the language

end Ada.Containers.Vectors;
```

Comment: Thx for answer. I knew about Vectors, but I tried to do it only using bounded arrays. For example my procedure takes a bounded array and returns another bounded array. But I think this is impossible. I mean, the very essence of Ada is to use bounded things.

Comment: `Ada.Containers.Bounded_Vectors`, [ARM A.18.19](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/rm12_w_tc1/html/RM-A-18-19.html)